# Handling Conflict in User ID Claims between ABP Framework and Firebase Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, firebase-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, abp

I'm currently developing an API using the ABP Framework. I have implemented the default authentication mechanism provided by the framework, and recently I integrated Firebase Auth as a third-party library to handle Google external authentication.

The challenge I'm facing is that my application validates two tokens: one generated by the app for username and password authentication, and the other generated by Firebase for external authentication. Both tokens contain a user ID claim.

In my code, I retrieve the user ID using `var userId = CurrentUser.Id.Value;`, which relies on the user ID being populated in the sub claim. However, Firebase Auth already utilizes this claim and doesn't allow for a custom value to be set.

I'm seeking a solution to handle this issue of conflicting user ID claims between ABP Framework and Firebase Auth. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.